# Is there a list of general use LaTeX kernel macros?

Tags: macros, documentation, latex-base

Here are a few cases in which one could use such a list:

- Is there a "prepend" version of `\g@addto@macro`? A "local" version?
- What's the most efficient way of gobbling n characters?
- Can I use LaTeX's internal macros to define my own starred commands?

etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- The `etoolbox` gives you local and global prepending macros `\preto`, `\gpreto`, `\epreto` and `\xpreto`.
- I would say use a version of `\@gobble` which takes *n* arguments. If you need to gobble more than 9 characters/tokens let the first macro expand to a second gobble macro. See [Benchmarking various operations of TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13192/benchmarking-various-operations-of-tex/13208#13208) for an discussion about this.
- Yes, sure you can, see [macros2e](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4790/documentation-reference-for-latex-internal-commands/10465#10465) in  [Documentation reference for LaTeX internal commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4790/documentation-reference-for-latex-internal-commands/) for a list of useful internal macros.

Comment: Does this mean this question is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4790/4012?

Comment: The general question is indeed a duplicate, but there also two specific tasks discussed here which makes the question IMHO valid to be on its own.

Answer (score 4):

To add some information regarding a local version of `\g@addto@macro`:

- KOMA-Script classes define `\l@addto@macro` as a local version.
- While `\gappto` from [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) works like `\g@addto@macro`, a local version is `\appto`. Prepending versions have been mentioned by Martin.