# Is it possible to make LaTeX retrieve date information from system clock?

Tags: datetime

Well, this question is pretty weird ;) I know TeX is strictly sandboxed, but I guess there is at least some possibility? After all, system clock (for instance, UNIX time on UNIX-like systems) is only 8 bytes or so in memory.

I would be very impressed if retrieving date information in LaTeX is actually possible! :D That way I would be able to create such a template that I do not need to adjust the date of each new article...

Comment: BTW If you need only date, there are counters like `\year` and `\month`.

Comment: @Eddy_Em Then how do you convert `\month` to "January", "February", etc.? A bunch of `if` statements?

Comment: See  http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13207/963

Comment: This is quite simple and realised in language packages: `\def\monthname{\ifcase\month\or January\or February… \fi}`

Comment: Where do you get the idea that TeX is 'strictly sandboxed'?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean something like that

```
cat wr.tex
...
\immediate\write18{date > date.tex}
\begin{document}
\input{date}
\end{document}

latex -enable-write18 wr.tex
```

??

If you don't need time but need only date, there are counters like `\year`, `\month` and `\day`.

To put current year in text say `\number\year`, to put month number use same construction. To put month name there must be a construction in your `babel` file like `\today` (puts today's date to document) or you can make construction like

```
\def\monthname{\ifcase\month\or January\or February\or March … \fi}
```

Then macro `\monthname` will write current month' name to the document.

Comment: Looks like magic..

Comment: No magic: `\write18` executes a shell command, `\immediate` do in right now (without it command can run in the end of compilation what can do an error in `\input`). By default (what if someone put `\write18{rm -rf ~}?)` `\write18` disabled, to enable it you must tell `-enable-write18` to latex.

Comment: Thanks for help. I accepted this but actually I prefer the counters you mentioned in comment. Could you please edit this answer to also include that method?

Comment: Done. I've added some info.

Comment: One should note that on Unix systems the option is `-shell-escape`, which is recognized also by the last versions of MiKTeX.

Comment: I work in linux, latex recognize `-enable-write18`

Answer (score 5):

However, the integer registers `\year`, `\month` and `\day` contain date information you probably need. Also `\time` contains the number of minutes from midnight when the job started.

For more detailed information, with `pdftex` (so with `latex` and `pdflatex` that use the same binary program), you can access the creation date that will be stamped in the PDF file with

```
\pdfcreationdate
```

which expands to a string of the form

```
D:20130115083308+01'00'
```

that is

```
D:YYYYMMDDHHMMSSshh'mm'
```

where s is `+` or `-` and together with `hh` and `mm` gives the local offset from UTC. The command is available also with `luatex` but *not* with XeTeX.

So, for instance, if you want to get the year, month and day, you can say

```
\def\getdate{\expandafter\getdateaux\pdfcreationdate}
\def\getdateaux#1#2#3'{\getdateaux#3'}
\def\getdateaux#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8{%
  \def\YEAR{#1#2#3#4}%
  \def\MONTH{#5#6}%
  \def\DAY{#7#8}}
```