# Is it possible to interact with TeX mid-process?

Tags: tex-core

Quoting from an answer to [Typesetting the entire Song That Never Ends](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95783/typesetting-the-entire-song-that-never-ends)

> I ran this code once, and aborted the process after it reported producing something like 47,000 pages (in a very short amount of time). Unfortunately, my computer complained that the resulting pdf file was "damaged" and could not be opened. A better (perhaps impossible?) answer would produce a file such that the output could actually be viewed once the process was killed (or died).

This got me curious (and it is merely a curiosity).  Can TeX die gracefully?  Since its output is a PDF, presumably it needs to do some non-trivial stuff at the end to ensure that the PDF is valid so merely killing TeX is too abrupt.

A more graceful method would be for TeX to ask at each shipout "Shall I continue?", but that suffers from the other extreme: it is too intrusive as the user needs to keep giving commands to keep TeX going.

Off the top of my head, the only way I can think of to communicate with a running process in a non-blocking way is via a file.  At each shipout (or other), TeX can check for the existence of a file and continue if it doesn't exist, and if it does then read the file and carry out whatever actions said file contains (thus allowing for more refined communication).

Is there a better way?

Comment: As per usual, I have absolutely no idea how to tag this one.

Comment: Suggested tag: `{to-TeX-or-not-to-TeX}`. `;)`

Comment: I think 'DVI mode' is the plan here, as each shipped out page can normally be viewed even if the run terminates

Comment: @JosephWright So then I can "kill" it and know that up to the previous shipout is viewable.  But what about the more refined version?  Suppose I want TeX to take some action other than dying after receiving a signal.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Just tell it not to die:-)

Comment: JFTR: If you hit `ctrl-c` and then `x` then also `pdftex` will produce a valid PDF.

Comment: @StephanLehmke I was hoping no-one would mention that - I just found it out when testing David's solution.  I claim I was misled by my client, y'honour.  (In that I assumed that that was what the person in the linked question had tried.)

Comment: (not having tested) I assume the 47,000 pages caused some sort of overflow and the PDF was invalid because of that...

Comment: @StephanLehmke Oddly enough, I haven't tested it up to that many pages either!  (Hopefully my question expands sufficiently on the original "die nicely" to survive this astonishing revelation.)

Comment: @StephanLehmke I don't know which client `Andrew` uses but when stopping a nonstopmode run with `C-cC-k` from within emacs, the dvi/pdf is corrupted and can not be opened via xdvi or a pdf viewer. However running from the command line, `ctrl-c` and then `X` does the trick as you said.

Comment: @jfbu Of course if you explicitly kill the TeX process, the PDF will be invalid. The same happens when killing the process from the console with `kill`. But in this case no amount of interaction will save you. When you abort by hitting `X`, you'll see the "postamble" in the console, loading fonts and such. So TeX is definitely finishing gracefully.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

Run this file

```
\def\resume{\let\foo\relax}

\count0=0
\def\foo{\advance\count0 1 \foo}

\foo\relax\relax\relax\relax

hello I reached \the\count0 before you stopped me

\bye
```

For a bit then stop it at the terminal (control-c in most shells) and enter i\resume and it will finish cleanly:

```
 pdftex oops
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./oops.tex
! Interruption.
\foo ->\advance \count 0 1
                           \foo 
l.7 \foo
        \relax\relax\relax\relax
? i\resume
[18672624{/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}
] )</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb
>
Output written on oops.pdf (1 page, 14709 bytes).
Transcript written on oops.log.
```

Comment: I like it!  Quick question: why all the `\relax`ing?

Comment: the `\relax` aren't needed in this version plan a was to stop the loop with a gobble command but depending on when exactly you hit ^C you needed to eat a different number of tokens so I stuck in some more so gobblefour was always safe but \let is better

Answer (score 10):

If you set `\pausing=1`, TeX will stop after each line of input read from the file.

Comment: What does "stop" mean in this context?  Will it halt completely, or will it wait for some "please continue" signal?  Either way, it seems to suffer from one of the issues I don't want as I basically want to be able to asynchronously send a signal to TeX.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: It will wait for user input. :-)

Comment: Right, so this is an implementation of my "graceful" method.  The problem with this one is that I have to keep telling it to continue.  What it would enable is having a controlling script which actually handled the signals and told TeX to keep going unless the script received the right signal.  So, useful, but not quite what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe setting a timer in `\everypar`? I used `\pdfelapsedtime` as shown in my post at [Benchmarking various operations of TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13192/benchmarking-various-operations-of-tex/13208#13208). In the MWE that illustrates the technique, I have used a simple

```
\ifdim\result sp <100000sp  \fibo \else Finish\fi
```

to do the time check. Code is rough and just a concept.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fp}   
\begin{document}
    \makeatletter
  \pdfresettimer 

\newcount\numbertimes
    \newcount\numone
    \newcount\numtwo 
    \newcount\savenumone
\def\fibonacci#1{..
    \numbertimes=2\numone=0
    \numtwo=1
    \loop
       \advance\numone  by  \numtwo  
       \savenumone=\the\numone  \numone=\numtwo  \numtwo=\savenumone 
       \advance\numbertimes  by 1 \ifnum \numbertimes<#1
    \repeat  
    \ifnum\numbertimes=#1 \advance\numone  by   \numtwo\fi 
    }



\def\fibo{%
\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}
\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}
\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}
\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}
\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}
\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}
\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}
\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}
\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}
\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}
\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}
\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}
\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}
\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}
\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}
\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}
\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}
\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}\fibonacci{30}
}

\fibo\fibo\fibo\fibo\fibo\fibo\fibo\fibo\fibo\fibo


\FPset\result{\the\pdfelapsedtime}
\FPmul\result{\result}{100} 
\FPround\result{\result}{16}
\result\thinspace 


\ifdim\result sp <100000sp  \fibo \else Finish\fi


\makeatother


\end{document}
```

Change the "Finish" to `\enddocument` to terminate.