# Package loading speeds

Tags: packages, profiling

Is there any benchmarking regarding which packages take longer to load than others?

Of course I know it depends on the computer you are running and perhaps even your Internet connection if you are loading them "on the fly", but that's why I'm asking for a benchmark... Has anyone actually taken the time to measure what packages take more time to load? Could this be considered a good point to speed up my work?

Comment: What would you do with the result?

Comment: I would like to know if, for example, `titleps` loads faster than `fancyhdr`

Comment: This question is very old, but I think it's the first time I've seen it.  The debate around benchmarking package loading boils down to: would you choose not to make use of a package solely because it took too long to load?

Comment: Link to related question, [tex core - Benchmarking various operations of TeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13192/benchmarking-various-operations-of-tex)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure why so many people are opposed to the idea of benchmarking in LaTeX. This seems totally reasonable and is something I've done to identify the bottlenecks in my own TeX code.

Fortunately, pdfTeX comes with two new handy primitives to control timing, `\pdfresettimer` and `\pdfelapsedtime`. The former resets the internal timer to 0 whereas the latter provides read-only access to the internal timer. The units are 1/65536 of a second.

Here's a simple macro that uses the `fp` package to convert the time into milliseconds.

```
\RequirePackage{fp}
\newcount\timer
% \Time\cs{thing to time}
\newcommand\Time[2]{%
        \pdfresettimer
        #2%
        \timer=\pdfelapsedtime
        \FPdiv#1{\the\timer}{65.536}%
        \FPtrunc#1#1{3}%
}
```

As the comment indicates, you use `\Time\foo{\usepackage{blah}}` to set `\foo` to the time in milliseconds it took to perform the code in the second argument.

It's possible to time `\documentclass` as well by putting the macro definition before `\documentclass` (hence the `\RequirePackage`).

Here's a complete example showing the timing of loading the `article` class and several packages.

```
\RequirePackage{fp}
\newcount\timer
% \Time\cs{thing to time}
\newcommand\Time[2]{%
        \pdfresettimer
        #2%
        \timer=\pdfelapsedtime
        \FPdiv#1{\the\timer}{65.536}%
        \FPtrunc#1#1{3}%
}

\Time\documentclasstime{\documentclass{article}}
\Time\tikztime{\usepackage{tikz}}
\Time\siunitxtime{\usepackage{siunitx}}
\Time\captoftime{\usepackage{capt-of}}
\Time\booktabstime{\usepackage{booktabs}}
\Time\graphicxtime{\usepackage{graphicx}}
\Time\hyperreftime{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\Time\mathptmxtime{\usepackage{mathptmx}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}lS@{}}
\toprule
Code & {Time (\si{\milli\second})}\\
\midrule
\verb!\documentclass{article}! & \documentclasstime \\
\verb!\usepackage{tikz}!       & \tikztime \\
\verb!\usepackage{siunitx}!    & \siunitxtime \\
\verb!\usepackage{capt-of}!    & \captoftime \\
\verb!\usepackage{booktabs}!   & \booktabstime \\
\verb!\usepackage{graphicx}!   & \graphicxtime \\
\verb!\usepackage{hyperref}!   & \hyperreftime \\
\verb!\usepackage{mathptmx}!   & \mathptmxtime \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It would likely not be too difficult to use `etoolbox`'s `\patchcmd` to patch `\usepackage` to perform the timing automatically, but I haven't done so here.

Similarly, it would be easy to create an environment rather than a command. This would have the advantage of not tokenizing the argument. But if you're going to go that route, `\pdfresettimer` and `\pdfelapsedtime` are just as easy to use directly.

One caveat with timing `\usepackage` is if you want to time multiple packages, one of which includes the other (or both include a common third package), then the order of your timing is going to matter. E.g., timing `\usepackage{siunitx}` followed by timing `\usepackage{expl3}` shows that `expl3` uses almost no time whereas `siunitx` takes significant time. Conversely, timing them in the opposite order shows that both take a moderate amount of time. `tikz` and `graphicx` have similar behavior. `graphicx` takes about 4 ms on my machine when loaded before `tikz` and as you can see from the table, about 1/100 of that when loaded afterward.

Comment: I'm not against benchmarking; my idea is that it's pretty useless in this case.

Comment: @egreg, fair enough. (And thanks for the `\patchcmd` fix.)

Comment: @egreg In my case, I write a bunch of package, they loads somewhat slowly and I want to determine which one does.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the [answer by TH.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/377051), one can benchmark from 'within' the TeX run using primitives available in pdfTeX/(u)pTeX, or by emulating the same in LuaTeX. Doing the same in XeTeX is not possible: one has to use system tools wrapped 'around' the TeX run. There will reveal some details, but focussing on package *loading* is probably the wrong place to worry. (Aside: the LaTeX team have some [experimental code for profiling](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/tree/master/l3trial/l3benchmark), but it's not currently released.)

One operation which takes a lot of time is opening separate files. For the same code, it's usually the case that a single file loads faster than lots of separate ones. This is one reason why 'custom' format files are loaded fast: see for example [Ultrafast PDFLaTeX with precompiling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79493/ultrafast-pdflatex-with-precompiling).

What makes a lot more *practical* difference is how careful code is in 'tight' situations, such as looping. Over time, that is something I've worked on in my own code and can be tricky to get right. For example, the LaTeX team have worked on the performance of `expl3`, and that has had a knock-on for anyone using the code.

Answer (score 2):

LaTeX packages are just text files. Once you have them on your computer, all are accesed the same way.

The more a package can do, the more code is involved and hence the file will be bigger. That means as well a longer time to load. On the other hand, packages load other packages to use their functions. Package `capt-of` has 33 lines of code, most of it commentaries, whereas package `siunitx` has over a thousand lines of code and requires the whole L3 kernel.

So instead of benchmarking, look at what the package can do and how it is implemented.

Comment: "instead of benchmarking": I'd say this request is a perfectly sensible one. Most users would like to know which packages are taking the longest to compile in. The suggested alternative to "look at what the package can do..." doesn't seem practical for most users.

Comment: @LondonRob LaTeX is just opening and reading the files. What takes time is producing the pdf by using that read in macros. What really is critical is the length of the document.

Comment: Loading packages is indeed a performance concern. See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79493/31839) for an example.

Comment: @LondonRob Apples and oranges.

Comment: @LondonRob Yes, but the big bottleneck is not how the files are structured internally but how many files there are. For example, `expl3` used to be lots of files, we made it into only two partly for this reason.

Comment: I pretty strongly disagree with the notion that one should not benchmark. Benchmarking is the only reliable way to determine how long something will actually take. Visual inspection is a sure-fire way to end up with premature optimizations.

Comment: @TH. Sure, but the real tiime spent in a normal (not MWE) document is the typesetting. That is why i do think there is no point in comparing package load time.

Comment: Ah, okay. I agree with that.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, LaTeX already provide some hooks to add some code to be executed on package load:

```
\makeatletter
\AddToHook{package/before}{\wlog{::::start loading \@currname : \the\pdf@elapsedtime}}
\AddToHook{package/after}{\wlog{::::done loading \@currname : \the\pdf@elapsedtime}}
```

Need package `pdftexcmds` for `\pdf@elapsedtime` (for portability between different engines)

Then just search for the lines with `::::` in the log file.

However... after getting the benchmark result, how to visualize them nicely is a bit nontrivial because there are so much content.

---

I wrote a small Python script to visualize the result (okay, use the right tool for the job. I could have written it in expl3 but what's the point?)

```python
input_log_file_path="/path/to/a.log"
output_file_name="/path/to/b.tex"

# ^^ fill in those 2. remember to escape `\' if you use them
# extra feature: `\wlog{::::mark something: \the\pdf@elapsedtime}' adds a marker with content `something'

time_scale=100
colors=["green!30!white", "blue!30!white", "red!30!white"]
first_coordinate=0.5
box_width=1.5
layer_separation=2
time_axis_length=27


import functools
lines=open(input_log_file_path, encoding='latin1').read()
printy=functools.partial(print, file=open(output_file_name, "w", encoding='u8'))

def set_globals_locals(globals, locals)->None:
    #if both are originally None
    #return caller's parent frame's globals and locals
    import sys
    # because of a Python bug https://bugs.python.org/issue21161 let's pass both as globals
    out=sys._getframe(1).f_locals
    if globals is None and locals is None:
        f=sys._getframe(2)
        return {**f.f_globals, **f.f_locals}, None
    else:
        pass
    return globals, locals

def evalz(s: str, globals=None, locals=None, escape_char=None)->None:
    globals, locals=set_globals_locals(globals, locals)

    if escape_char is None:
        escape_char=next(ch for ch in "%!@" if ch in s)

    parts=s.split(escape_char)
    result=[]
    for i in range(len(parts)):
        if i%2==0:
            result.append(parts[i])
        elif parts[i]=="": # %% → %
            result.append(escape_char)
        else:
            try:
                item=eval(parts[i], globals, locals)
            except:
                import sys
                printy("Error while executing code ========\n"+ parts[i] + "\n========", file=sys.stderr)
                raise
            result.append(
                    item if isinstance(item, str) else
                    str(item) if isinstance(item, int) else
                    __import__("sympy").latex(item)
                    )
    return "".join(result)

def printz(s: str, globals=None, locals=None, escape_char: str=None, end: str=None)->None:
    globals, locals=set_globals_locals(globals, locals)
    printy(evalz(s, globals, locals, escape_char=escape_char), end=end)




printz(
r"""%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{tooltip}
%\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1]
    \draw [->] (0, 0) -- (0, $time_axis_length$);
    \def\a#1#2{
    \draw (0.1, #1) -- (-0.1, #1) node [left] {#2};
}

"""
, escape_char="$")




import re
items=[]
mark_event=object()
for line in lines.splitlines():
    if not line.startswith("::::"): continue
    match=re.fullmatch(r"::::(?:(start|done) loading ([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)|mark (.*)): (\d+)", line)
    assert match, line
    moment: float=int(match[4])/65536
    if match[3]:
        items.append((mark_event, match[3], moment))
    else:
        is_start: bool=match[1]=="start"
        package_name: str=match[2]
        items.append((is_start, package_name, moment))

initial_skip=items[0][2]
def time_to_coordinate(t: float)->float:
    return (t-initial_skip)*time_scale

for t in range(0, 50):
    t/=50
    if t>=initial_skip and time_to_coordinate(t)<=time_axis_length:
        printz(r"\a{%time_to_coordinate(t)%}{%t%}")

mark_last_y=time_to_coordinate(-1)
mark_y_separation=0.25

package_stack=[]
for is_start, package_name, moment in items:
    if not is_start and not package_stack:
        continue

    if is_start is mark_event:
        layer=len(package_stack)

        red_line_left=first_coordinate+layer_separation*(layer-1)+box_width
        red_line_right=red_line_left+box_width/2
        y_coordinate=time_to_coordinate(moment)

        node_y_coordinate=mark_last_y=max(mark_last_y+mark_y_separation, y_coordinate)

        printz(
        r"""\draw[red] (%red_line_left%, %y_coordinate%)
                -- (%red_line_right%, %y_coordinate%);
        \path (%red_line_right%, %node_y_coordinate%) node [black, right] {\small %package_name%};
        """
        )
    elif is_start:
        package_stack.append((package_name, moment))
    else:
        package_name1, start_moment=package_stack.pop()
        assert package_name1==package_name
        
        layer=len(package_stack)

        #package_name_t=evalz(r"\pdftooltip{t}{%package_name%}")
        package_name_t=package_name

        color=colors[layer%len(colors)]

        printz(
        r"""\fill[%color%] (
            %first_coordinate+layer_separation*layer%,
            %time_to_coordinate(start_moment)%
        ) rectangle 
        (
            %first_coordinate+box_width+layer_separation*layer%,
            %time_to_coordinate(moment)%
        ) node [black, midway] {\small %package_name_t%};
        """
        )

        



printy(
r"""
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
"""
)
```

Run the script, then compile the generated TeX file.

Output may look like this

[image: example output]

(turns out my packages doesn't load that slow, relatively speaking. And why is the gap between packages so large?)

Comment: Hm actually TikZ already have profiler library or something. Better see if I reinvented something.

Comment: (update later) Turns out my LaTeX release uses a ["very slow filename normalisation"](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=60905339#60905339) algorithm which adds a certain overhead per package.