# Patching \usepackage / \RequirePackage

Tags: patching, xpatch, profiling

I want to implement automatic benchmarking for the packages I load (some of which are my own). Right now my preamble takes 15 seconds to load, much longer than the rest of my document seems to take to compile.

For this I wanted to implement a remark from this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/377051/197635), which recommended using `etoolbox`'s `patchcmmd` to patch `usepackage`. As most of my package loading happens inside of my own packages, I wanted to use this approach on `RequirePackage`. I opted however to use `xpatch`'s utilities, as I had read that the normal `patchcmd` can't deal with commands with optional arguments.

My best try so far is this (please don't mind the ugly automatic output via AfterEndPreamble):

```
\RequirePackage{fp}
\RequirePackage{xpatch}
\newcount\timer

\xpretocmd{\RequirePackage}{\pdfresettimer}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\RequirePackage}{
    \timer=\pdfelapsedtime
    \FPdiv\temp{\the\timer}{65.536}
    \FPtrunc\temp\temp{3}
    \AfterEndPreamble{\par{#1:} \temp}
}{}{}

% Testing 
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{mathtools}

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

But sadly this produces an Error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `\timer.sty' not found.
```

My best guess is that this is because `ProvideCommand` has a second optional argument after the normal one and `xpatchcmd` can't handle that, causing `ProvideCommand` to consume the appended text as it's main argument. But I'm way out of my comfort zone here, and I have not managed to understand `ProvideCommand` via `\show` so far (and I assume there must be a better way of just patching a command with surrounding code anyway, without knowing its internal structure). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asking `latexdef RequirePackage` yields

```
% latex.ltx, line 10034:
\def\RequirePackage{%
  \@fileswithoptions\@pkgextension}
```

Oh, well, now we need to do `latexdef @fileswithoptions`

```
% latex.ltx, line 10097:
\def\@fileswithoptions#1{%
  \@ifnextchar[%]
    {\@fileswith@ptions#1}%
    {\@fileswith@ptions#1[]}}
```

which means that the macro absorbs one token or one braced argument and tests if a `[` comes along. If you add those tokens at the end of `\RequirePackage`, the argument passed to `\@fileswithoptions` will be `\@pkgextension` and the test for `[` will return false, so we'd end up with

```
\@fileswith@ptions\@pkgextension\timer=\pdfelapsedtime
```

and this will fail as you see, because

```
\def\@fileswith@ptions#1[#2]#3{%
  \@ifnextchar[%]
  {\@fileswith@pti@ns#1[{#2}]#3}%
  {\@fileswith@pti@ns#1[{#2}]#3[]}}
```

so argument `#3` will be `\timer` instead of a list of file names (without extensions).

Sorry, but this is not going to work in any sensible way, because of nested `\RequirePackage` done by the packages you load.

```
\RequirePackage{fp}
\newcount\timer

\newcommand{\TimeRequirePackage}[1]{%
  \pdfresettimer
  \RequirePackage{#1}%
  \timer=\pdfelapsedtime
  \FPdiv\temp{\the\timer}{65.536}%
  \FPtrunc\temp\temp{3}%
  \printresult{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\printresult}[1]{\expandafter\printresultaux\expandafter{\temp}{#1}}
\newcommand{\printresultaux}[2]{\AtBeginDocument{\par#2: #1}}

% Testing 
\TimeRequirePackage{tikz}
\TimeRequirePackage{mathtools}

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that you need to expand `\temp` before passing it to `\AtBeginDocument` (not `\AtEndPreamble`).

With `xfp`

```
\RequirePackage{xfp}

\newcommand{\TimeRequirePackage}[1]{%
  \pdfresettimer
  \RequirePackage{#1}%
  \expanded{\noexpand\AtBeginDocument{\par#1: \fpeval{round(\pdfelapsedtime/65.536,3)}}}
}

% Testing 
\TimeRequirePackage{tikz}
\TimeRequirePackage{mathtools}

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, I had hoped there would be a more general solution. Is there an easy way to define this command `\TimeRequirePackage` in a way that it can deal with the `\RequirePackage[options]{package}[date]` commands? `\IfValueTF` deals well with the `\RequirePackage[options]{package}` case. I have a few of those `\RequirePackage` commands with date in my files. In fact, I think this was the reason I initially tried the approach of patching the command via xpatch.

Comment: Also, regarding the nested `\RequirePackage`s, couldn't I just use `\csname #1time \endcsname` (with appropriate `\expandafter`s) instead of `\temp` and then use differences in `\pdfelapsedtime` instead of resetting the pdf timer each time the command is invoked? Or is there some more fundamental obstacle to this?

Answer (score 4):

You could use (with a new latex) the package hooks to define a list of packages that should be measured (the calculation is stolen from egregs answer):

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\BenchmarkPackages}[1]
 {%
  \clist_map_inline:nn{#1}
   {
    \AddToHook{package/before/##1}{\pdfresettimer}
    \AddToHook{package/after/##1}{\typeout{##1: \fp_eval:n{round(\pdfelapsedtime/65.536,3)}}}
   } 
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\BenchmarkPackages{tikz,mathtools,scrbase}


\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
alblb
\end{document}
```

This will then write something like tikz:1085.999 in the log (one could naturally also store the value and print it later).